# How do I get a list of bundles?

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 8+, how do I programmatically get a list of bundles for an entity type, for example the list of content types. Specifically, I'm looking for the machine names.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the bundles for an entity type, use the *entity_type.bundle.info* service.

```php
$bundle_info = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo($entity_type);
```

As usual, use dependency injection whenever possible.

See [`EntityTypeBundleInfo::getBundleInfo()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityTypeBundleInfo.php/function/EntityTypeBundleInfo%3A%3AgetBundleInfo/8.5.x) for more information. In particular, see what the method returns.

> An array of bundle information where the outer array is keyed by the bundle name, or the entity type name if the entity does not have bundles. The inner arrays are associative arrays of bundle information, such as the label for the bundle.

As example of Drupal core code that uses that service, see `content_translation_entity_extra_field_info()`.

```php
$extra = [];
$bundle_info_service = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info');
foreach (\Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinitions() as $entity_type => $info) {
  foreach ($bundle_info_service->getBundleInfo($entity_type) as $bundle => $bundle_info) {
    if (\Drupal::service('content_translation.manager')->isEnabled($entity_type, $bundle)) {
      $extra[$entity_type][$bundle]['form']['translation'] = [
        'label' => t('Translation'),
        'description' => t('Translation settings'),
        'weight' => 10,
      ];
    }
  }
}

return $extra;
```

Comment: This is the best approach. I believe It lacks bundle description and some additional information you need to fetch manually.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get bundles of an entity type via drush the command is

```
drush php-eval "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo('ENTITY_TYPE')));"
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s basically the same answer as above, but the function returns an array with **all bundles** e.g all entity types and all their bundles , i´m still pasting this here for convenience in case anyone might find this useful.

```
 DI service-names: 
  - '@entity_type.manager'
  - '@entity_field.manager'
  - '@entity_type.bundle.info'
```

---

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeBundleInfoInterface;
```

---

```
  /**
   * Entity type manager.
   *
   * @var Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  /**
   * The entity field manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityFieldManager;

  /**
   * The entity type bundle info.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeBundleInfoInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeBundleInfo;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, EntityFieldManagerInterface $entity_field_manager, EntityTypeBundleInfoInterface $entity_type_bundle_info) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->entityFieldManager = $entity_field_manager;
    $this->entityTypeBundleInfo = $entity_type_bundle_info;
  }
```

---

```
  public function getEntityTypesWithBundles() {
    $types_with_bundles = [];
    foreach($this->entityTypeManager->getDefinitions() as $entity_name => $entity_definition) {
      $types_with_bundles[$entity_name] = [
        "machine_name" => $entity_name,
        "bundles" => []
      ];
    }
    foreach ($types_with_bundles as $entity_type_key => &$entity_type) {
      foreach ($this->entityTypeBundleInfo->getBundleInfo($entity_type_key) as $bundle => $bundle_info) {
        $entity_type['bundles'][] = $bundle;
      }
    }
    return $types_with_bundles;
  }
```